# How to set "ref" for a child component that is received as props in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, components

When I use a child component directly, I can set "ref" like this:

```
<Child ref={myRef}/>
```

But, assume we have a parent component and some children components like this that passed as props:

```
export interface IProps {
  Tools: React.ReactNode[];
}
    
export interface IState {
  Tools: React.ReactNode[];
}
    
export class ParentComponent extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {

  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      Tools: this.props.Tools
    };
  }

  render(): React.ReactNode {
    const child = React.createRef();
    return (<h1>{this.state.Tools[0]}</h1>);
  }
}

export default ParentComponent;
```

How can I set "ref" for children when I received children from an array of (React.ReactNode[])?

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. If it's props it's not state (usually, most of the time)
2. use [`cloneElement`](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/cloneElement)

```
export class ParentComponent extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {

  refForTools = React.createRef()

  render(): React.ReactNode {
    const child = React.cloneElement(this.props.Tools[0], {ref: this.refForTools})
    return (<h1>{child}</h1>);
  }
}

export default ParentComponent;
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-s9jx1m?file=App.tsx

This question is almost certainly an XY problem - what are you trying to do and why? refs should be used very sparingly and cloneElement is quite uncommon unless you're writing a library.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In fact, I need to have a parent component (for example a report manager) that has some children (for example some tools for reporting). In this situation, I need to pass some desired tools to the parent component pragmatically (like a dependency injection process). On the other hand, I used "cloneElement", but there is a big problem, in this case, I need my child components to have a binding state like a normal component. but, by using "cloneElement", they don't have it.